# How does GAlib-mpi achieve parallelization

Tags: c++, mpi, genetic-algorithm, galib

How does GAlib-mpi achieve parallelization. Are individuals moved across populations run on different cores/processors, or are they simply run in parallel independent of each other without any migration?

---

In case someone else needs this. I asked same question as an issue on GitHub ... The author of the library replied with:

> All individuals exist in all cores/processors. Their scored is shared so each core/processor only computes a subset of the individual scores. In my case this was the time-consuming process.

See link [to GitHub issue here](https://github.com/B0RJA/GAlib-mpi/issues/5)